# I have error when migrating my db in django-python

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework

i change my database django default to postgresql and when i try to migrating ...
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hamid"`

my settings is
install psycop2 but i dont understad my mistake becuse i can enter to shell database by this password but when i migrating i have error

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USRE': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  blogpy_postgresql:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: blogpy_postgresql
    volumes:
      - blogpy_postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    env_file:.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - blogpy_network

volumes:
  blogpy_postgresql:
    external: true
networks:
  blogpy_network:
    external: true
```

and my .env

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
```

and my traceback

```
File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hamid"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/hamid/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hamid"
```

i use python3
and django 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your databases settings.

```
'USRE': 'postgres',
```

should be

```
'USER': 'postgres',
```